# SQL picking same entry multiple times

Tags: sql

```
  SELECT p.*
    FROM StatusUpdates p
    JOIN FriendRequests fr
      ON (fr.From = p.AuthorId OR fr.To = p.AuthorId)
   WHERE fr.To = ".$Id." OR fr.From = ".$Id." 
     AND fr.Accepted = 1
ORDER BY p.DatePosted DESC
```

I'm using this SQL code at the moment which somone wrote for me on a different question. I'm using PHP, but that shouldn't make much difference, since the only thing I'm doing with it is concatenating a variable into it.

What it's meant to do is go through all your friends and get all their status posts, and order them. It works fine, but it picks out "$Id"'s posts either not at all, or the amount of friends you have

Eg, if you had 5 friends, it would pick our your posts 5 times. I only want it to do this once. How could I do this?

Comment: Yes (Have to post more characters to get past minimum of 15 character limit)

Comment: a better technique than padding a 'yes' comment is to edit your question and (a) mention the DBMS (MySQL) in the question, and (b) add a mysql tag.  And if you must pad, you could write: "Yes, I am using MySQL" which gets you past the limit.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that in future. Apologies, I couldn't think of anything else to put at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of join if you want to display post id regardless of number of friends. And `GROUP BY p.id` in order not to display the same posts more than 1 time:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM StatusUpdates p
LEFT JOIN FriendRequests fr
  ON ((fr.From = p.AuthorId OR fr.To = p.AuthorId) AND fr.Accepted = 1)
 WHERE p.AuthorId = ".$Id."

GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.DatePosted DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed all the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Either `GROUP BY p.id` or `SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.*`

Comment: Thanks, implemented and works. It still only picks the user's posts if they have at least 1 friend, though. Is there any easy fix to get around this, or would it be easier to trick the system by giving everyone a fake friend?